# How to prevent collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath delegate method called more than once

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

When i tap one of UICollectionView's cell more than once-double tap, triple tap-, it's delegate method didSelectItemAtIndexPath also get called more than once. What can be the slickest way to prevent it?

I would appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your model object to hold selected property in it (or you can create a boolean array for only this purpose) . And check it in shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath method.

**@cihangirs code:**

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    if (someModel.isSelected) { 
        return NO; 
    } else { 
        someModel.isSelected = YES; 
        return YES; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is safest way to do your objective:-**

```
 (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if([[collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] containsObject:indexPath]) // checking whether cell is already selected or not
    {
      return;
    }
 else
   {
 // do whatever you want to do on selection of cell

   }
}
```

The thing happening here is, whenever you select a cell it automatically get stored "indexPathsForSelectedItems" of Collection view, so the next time you tap on the selected cell again this method `[[collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] containsObject:indexPath]` will check whether that cell is already selected or not , if yes then it will return the method so that it doesnot go any step further.